# How can I update the data that is being replicated in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I use the SQL SERVER 2008 replication mechanism which takes data from server A (master) and replicates it to server B, C and D. The tables that are being replicated have a clientID field, which I would like the actual replication to update depending whether the data is going to B, C or D. 
Is this possible?

Comment: Not that I know of. Easy workaround: create a view on each destination server that hard-codes B, C or D as a column.

Comment: That is what we are doing. The master has data for all clients (B,C and D) and when the data gets pushed to each client, each client has a view that filters the data based on this clientId column in each table. This is temporary mechanism as I understand, and I like not to add any code on the master to update this clientId and was hoping there was a way to update this column "in process" of replication.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Implement a Business Logic Handler for a Merge Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147911.aspx).